# Conditional Formatting Dates whereby specific date range auto-suggests action

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am in the process of creating a documentation tracker however struggling to do the following:

1. add conditional formatting so that the background changes colour (green, yellow, red) based on how many days since documentation has last been reviewed/updated. So that the background colours change depending on the number of days or months whichever is easier.
2. Based on the date, in the Action column for any dates greater than 3 months/90 days want it to automatically indicate check likewise for dates within a month or less no need to check

Link to documentation tracker google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DTyEg7JQcrTqCFQqgxrJEadOG8PcnI5khOrpOssZvyo/edit?usp=sharing

Example of a document which i got the status idea:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8CXs-Q4qs7KeykxAlBF2cGfw7th-DGIqle6yLAVOxE/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance! Will be extremely grateful for any help, guidance and advice!

Comment: You need to provide more details, and it is easier to help you if you make your sheet editable by everyone.  Is it just the date field you want formatted in colour?  And is it RED if it is older than 90 days, YELLOW if older than 30, etc?

Comment: Just made it editable and just the date field for now however keen to know how to expand it to the days elapsed field, I also noticed may be using the wrong function =DAYS360. Also the colour allocation to meaning is right

Comment: Please clarify what "expand it to the days elapsed field" means.  Do you just want the coloured background added to the "days elapsed" field?  I've done that in tab GK-Sheet1 in your sample sheet.  I've also used a formula to calculate the "days elapsed" column, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've provided so far, here is the basic conditional formatting to get you started.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_AvM9sPlxUSlToqWf7t6oSKak5K7ALc_S4XjgO5o4q0/edit?usp=sharing

The custom formula for the conditional formatting looks like this:

```
=AND(TODAY()-E2 > 90, E2 <> "")
```

So if the date in E2 is older than 90 days, mark that cell in RED.  This rule applies to the whole column, E2:E.

Similarly, a checkmark is added in the Action column for dates older than 90 days, by the formula in F1.  Do you also mean that dates less than 30 days old should be always unchecked, but dates between 90 and 30 days, should be left as they are, either checked or not?

Let us know if this is what you are hoping for.

Update: The Action column is calculated based on the difference between today's date and your date value in Column E.  It is really duplicating the RED highlighting, so doesn't really help you.  If it is a field that you want to be able to update, you'll probably need to change the Arrayformula to a dragdown formula, which you cana then overtype if putting a checkmark in a cell.

Comment: @kirkg12 thanks for the explanation and taking your time to help! By the dates I mean what you said dates less than 30 days old should be always unchecked, but dates between 90 and 30 days, should be left as they are, either checked or not?

However kind of confused:

=and(today()-E2 > 15,E2<>"")  yellow
=and(today()-E2 <16,E2<>"") green
=and(today()-E2 > 100,E2<>"") red

why do you use them numbers 15,16,100 instead of using something like 90 for 3 months?

Comment: I changed the numbers in the conditional formatting.  You hadn't specified which date ranges to use for the colours in your original question.  Let me know if this is what you want, or if there is still an issue.

Comment: Hi @kirkg12 thanks for the help however created an altered version. I am trying to replicate the "action" column into this altered version of the doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7AW4AXMJfntoq_kuZjJMekYkvf0bn1oA248JE96ako/edit?usp=sharing. Need some guidance please currently with the formula, as I get the message Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in I3.

Comment: @Ajiri, the reason for the error message is that "inserting" checkboxes in I3:I prevents the ArrayFormula from creating the values in that column.  Instead, select I3:I, and apply Data Validation (from Data menu), with Criteria = Checkbox.  This turns the TRUE or FALSE values from the ArrayFormula to show as checkboxes.     I also changed the formula in I2 to check the dates in H3:H.   It had been pointing to F3:F.  Let me know if this is what you want, or if you need more formatting help.  Note that the checkboxes are misleading - you can't click them to change values.

Comment: The checkboxes in I3:I are just showing you information that the conditional formating of the date values in H3:H already shows - red if older than 120 days, green if equal to today, etc...

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation, understood now for the summaries column, how would one go about and enable the column in each product category to pick up the most frequent colour? For example product 1 product category will pick up yellow , technical red and so on

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you please clarify.  Perhaps show on a sheet what the data starts like, and what colours you would like added to that data?  What does "technical red" mean?  What is "product 1 product category"?

Comment: my bad i was not clear.

I have added another tab called "iteration 2", what I am doing manually with the summaries section I want it done in an automatic way maybe using conditional formatting. The iterated datasheet shows what the data starts like and what colours are expected, where the colours in the summaries section are controlled by the most frequent colour in the "last reviewed/last updated" column. Hope it makes sense

Comment: An example in iteration 2 tab which is currently done manually:

Product 1 summary colours are yellow, red, green for each of the documentation categories. It picks up these colours from the most frequent colour in each documentation category, specifically "Last Reviewed / Last Updated" column. 
Product 2 colours are similar however stakeholder summary category is yellow because yellow is the most common/frequent colour. I have also tried to visualise the question :https://www.loom.com/share/ba762795a0694e66bfaf8ea642267dc2

Comment: Okay, the video helped explain what you want to do, and it should be possible.  That is because the same logic that is used to set the colours based on the dates of your documentation, will also be used to set the colours in your summary columns.  But I have a question.  What colour should show if you have two reds, and two yellow dates?  Or two red and two green?

Comment: See new answer below.

Comment: Is there any reason for column J?  It just shows a check if column I is red, so it duplicates information that is already available...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is not a very elegant solution, and I know some experts would have a much better solution, but I think it does what you want.
See my tab "Iteration 2-GK" in your new sheet.

You can change the dates in column I to see if the Summaries colours change the way you expect.  I haven't done Technical or Stakeholders yet, but they would be the same.

I came up with a complex formula to apply the same logic used in the conditional formatting rules for Column I, to apply conditional formatting for column C.  Note that I added a hidden column B, to add the ProductName onto each row.  I also removed the merged cells in columns A-E.
The formula to check whether the dates in column I fall in a certain range, and then to count which range occurs most frequently (ie. also the most frequent colour in column I for each product) is:

```
=iferror(choose( 
   match(
   max( 
    {iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today()-180,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) '' ",0),""), 
     iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today()-31,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(today()-180,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) ''",0), ""), 
     iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today() ,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(today()-31, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) ''",0), "")}), 
    {iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today()-180,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) '' ",0),""), 
     iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today()-31,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(today()-180,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) ''",0), ""), 
     iferror(query({B$3:B,I$3:I},
            "select count(Col2) where Col1 = '"& B3 & "' and Col2 < date '"&TEXT(today() ,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 >= date '"&TEXT(today()-31, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col2) ''",0), "")}, 
  0),"red","yellow","green"),"")
```

I haven't got this to work, so it needs to be dragged down column C from cell C3.

Will you need to add rows for a product, if you come up with more documentation?  I haven't tested yet if this will work when adding rows.